# Triggering key event without EditText from KeyboardView

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, ui-testing, android-instrumentation

The standard way of triggering key event could look like this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edit_text), isDisplayed())).perform(ViewActions.pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0));
```

What to do if there is no target view( `edit_text` ) but there is custom [Keyboard](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) with just listener `setOnKeyboardActionListener`?

Comment: you want to send key event to your Keyboard??

Comment: @user1506104 I want to make `setOnKeyboardActionListener` triggered.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to set the custom **android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView** to the **withID** method, and to using the **pressKey** method with KeyEvent.**KEYCODE_NUMPAD_0** instead of KEYCODE_0:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.keyboardview), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_0));
```